# How do I use polymer starter kit from polymer cli in a node and express app?

Tags: node.js, express, polymer, polymer-starter-kit, polymer-cli

polymer starter kit provides a template to develop client-logic

**polymer build** creates a bundled and unbundled version.

how do i use this in a node js application using express without loosing the **PRPL** concepts by default the polymer starter kit provides

As the **polymer server** starts its own server to run the bundled version.

With nodejs & Express. Below is how i render HTML on inital load in a normal client-server application

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express.createServer();

app.use(express.staticProvider(__dirname + '/public'));

app.get('/', function(req, res) {
    res.render('index.html');
});

app.listen(8080, '127.0.0.1')
```

But for Polymer starter kit it has polymer.json file which defines lile below

```
{
  "entrypoint": "index.html",
  "shell": "src/my-app.html",
  "fragments": [
    "src/my-view1.html",
    "src/my-view2.html",
    "src/my-view3.html",
    "src/my-view404.html"
  ],
  "sourceGlobs": [
   "src/**/*",
   "images/**/*",
   "bower.json"
  ],
  "includeDependencies": [
    "manifest.json",
    "bower_components/webcomponentsjs/webcomponents-lite.min.js"
  ]
}
```

How to use Polymer starter kits generated bundled folder in a node and express app?

Answer (score 4):

As no one Answered my question for a week, i found solution for this. Use below code in the bundled/unbundled folder in the build folder, after executing polymer build.

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express.createServer();

app.use(express.staticProvider(__dirname + '/public'));

app.get('/', function(req, res) {
    res.render('index.html');
});

app.listen(8080, '127.0.0.1')
```

Use it like a normal client-server application.

Comment: thanks for coming back and answering your own question. any chance you could show your folder structure after doing this?

Comment: also wondering if you are still using CLI to run from the command line